# How to apply a mask to a numpy array maintaining shape and retrieving values?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I'm doing a image segmentation where I created a mask (bool array). I now want to extract the imaging data at the mask region while keeping the shape of my image array.

As the image data would be too large, here a shortened form of my problem:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([False, False, True, True])
```

This is what I essentially want:

```py
c = np.array([False, False, 3, 4])
  = np.array([0, 0, 3, 4])
```

I tried various slicing methods including:

```py
a[b]
np.extract()
np.choose()
np.take
```

These, however, either don't return the shape of the array or only return a bool.

Thanks for any help.
BBQuercus

Comment: `a*b` is probably the simplest one

Comment: That works too. Apparently things don't have to be as complicated as they first look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
np.where(b, a, 0)
# np.array([0, 0, 3, 4])
```